# Read from Ten Text files (or multiple text files) in a single line of code?

Tags: java, histogram, file-handling

So I'm trying to read ten text files at the same time and my goal is to have a shorter code. Is there any way to code it from a single line of code? Because i want a shorter code/way. Here's my code:

```
while (((a = First.readLine()) != null) || (a = Second.readLine()) != null)
```

P.S. i'm coding a histogram....

Comment: Focus on making your code more readable. If making it shorter sacrifices readability, I'd recommend against it.

Comment: Any reason do you want a shorter code?

Comment: While shorter code may not increase readability, not nesting loops may. Consider using a [SequenceInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/SequenceInputStream.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the dirPath for the folder that contains all the archives.

```
Files.walk(Paths.get(dirPath)).forEach(filePath -> {readArchive(filePath);});
```